# MySQL Workbench - Disable User-defined variable caching?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here's the shortest example I have:

**Step 01)**

```
SELECT @var;
```

This will return NULL because @var has not been initialized.

**Step 02)**

```
SELECT @var:=9001
```

This will return 9001.

**Step 03)**

```
SELECT @var;
```

In MySQL Workbench's query tab, this will return 9001, still. I have to set it to NULL myself.

I don't want MySQL Workbench to cache the value of a user-defined variable between queries in the query tab. Disabling it is useful when I'm trying to build and test a query that uses user-defined variables.

I did some searching but I couldn't phrase my question the right way because I kept getting the answer to use SQL_NO_CACHE which won't work in this case. (I tried it.)

Comment: not sure what the problem is. you set the value to 9001 in your second query, and it'll STAY at that value for the life of that particular connection to the db, or until you change/delete the value. That's not workbench cacheing anything. That's the db properly keeping that variable 'alive'.

Comment: It's not desirable behaviour when I'm trying to build and test a query that will only execute once per connection (like in a PHP page). I don't want to have to reconnect/manually set to null after every time I test the query inside the query tab in MySQL workbench.

Comment: But if there really is no way around it, then I kinda' have to bite the bullet and run a "reset" query.

Comment: There is no caching. How do you come to that conclusion? A variable is bound to a session and keeps the value you assign to it last. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Okay, so maybe it's not caching. But it is remembering the value of a user-defined variable between queries in the same session. How do I get around this in the MySQL workbench short of re-connecting/running a reset query?